# Switching language within alltt environment in xelatex

Tags: xetex, packages, languages

How can one use more than one language in XeLaTeX within the `\alltt` environment?

I have to issues doing this using babel and compiling with pdfLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
 this is a test
\foreignlanguage{greek}{αυτό είναι μια δοκιμή}
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

but if I try something similar when compiling with XeLaTeX: ([view example in ShareLateX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/542186fa7ce697b21169b47e)) the text in greek does not appear in the compiled pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{alltt}
% Times New Roman
\setmainfont[BoldFont=timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=timesbi.ttf
]{times.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
this is a test 
αυτό είναι μια δοκιμή 
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a monospaced font that has Greek characters. For instance

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{alltt}

\setmainfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*bd,
  ItalicFont=*i,
  BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]{times}

\setmonofont{cmuntt.otf} % or any other monospaced font supporting Greek

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
this is a test
αυτό είναι μια δοκιμή
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

[image]